# How do I access a Bokeh (Python) variable with JS?

Tags: javascript, bokeh, bokehjs

I'm making a dropdown which displays a certain plot depending on what is selected.

I've made my dropdown and begun my CustomJS callback function. At the moment, all I want to do is log whatever option is selected in the dropdown, but obviously I cant just console.log(myDropDownMenu.value);

```
myDropDownMenu = Select(options=['uniform', 'normal', 'lognormal'], value='uniform', title='Distribution')

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code=
                    """
console.log("What should go in here?");
""")

myDropDownMenu.js_on_change('value', callback)
```

So if 'uniform' is selected in the dropdown, I expect 'uniform' to show up in my console... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the callback object `cb_obj` and callback data `cb_data` are available in each JS callback. Additionally, when using `args` callback attribute you can pass arbitrary number of additional objects as long as they are serializable (like `source` in your example). In your case `this` is the `cb_object` so you can access it's `value` property. You may consider using e.g. Google Chrome developers tools (ALT+CMD+I on Mac) to view and inspect those objects in JS console.

Comment: Thanks Tony. It's these little things I need to know that the docs I've seen don't seem to cover.

Answer (score 1):

Who would've known it was this easy?

```
console.log(this.value);
```

Rubber duck debugging at it's finest.